# What is the use of asp.net identity .GenerateUserToken()

Tags: asp.net-identity

I understand that token from userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken() is used to add as a security identifier in the hyperlink  to send to user on password reset request.

But I am not sure what the user of userManager.GenerateUserToken() . I am able to generate the token ,
but not sure if this can be converted to claims like SAML tokens and be used for authorization .

Please help me understand this as I was not able to find any good documentation regarding this .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`GenerateUserToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions.generateusertoken.aspx) is used to create password-reset tokens and email-confirmation tokens. This method takes string parameter `purpose` that is describing what sort of operation is going to happen. Effectively this `purpose` is an encryption key that is used to decrypt the generated token.

So you can create your own tokens for your own purposes, for example you can have `ConfirmJobOffer` operation in recruitment application. And you can create token just for that operation and sent the link with this token to a user:

```cs
var token = userManager.GenerateUserToken(userId, "ConfirmJobOffer");
// now send this token as part of the link
```

Then in controller, once the token made back to you you can call:

```cs
var tokenCorrect = await userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, "ConfirmJobOffer", token);
if (tokenCorrect)
{
    // do stuff if token is correct
}
```

Generally you would not use `GenerateUserToken` directly, unless you are doing custom tokens. You'd use [`GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497549.aspx) and [`GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497544.aspx).

Please note: this is is not aimed to do SAML tokens or related authorization.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to trailmax's answer...

This line from the answer has the parameter swapped:

```
var token = userManager.GenerateUserToken(userId, "ConfirmJobOffer");
```

Will generate

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'UserId not found.'

It Should read:

```
var token = userManager.GenerateUserToken("ConfirmJobOffer",userId);
```

I tried editing the post and it got rejected. I can see where it looks a little confusing...but TUser is the user supplied Key or "purpose" and TKey is the userId.

From the [UserManagerExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn384551%28v%3Dvs.108%29) class:

```
public static string GenerateUserToken<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, string purpose, TKey userId)
    where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>;
```